# My rejected promise in AUTH_CHECK don't do anything

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

In the AUTH_CHECK of my authprovider i validate my token :

```
if (type === AUTH_CHECK) {
            return isTokenValid(localStorage.getItem('token')) ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject()
}
```

After my rejected promise my resource is called, i can see it in my browser's console :

```
GET https://localhost:88/api/1/myresource 401
```

After that, my Login form i s called.
So why calling my resource to detect the unauthorized acces ?
I already rejected my promise before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because react-admin optimistically renders its UI before the authProvider call returns in order to avoid empty pages

Comment: Thanks, so AUTH_CHECK does not really check the user authentification ?

Comment: It does check the user auth, that's why it redirect to the login page once it gets the authprovider response

Comment: So each time the token was not valid it is really needed to call the api ? we are calling an api for nothing.

Comment: That's the choice we made yes. Feel free to fork the project and handle those cases as you see fit.

Comment: Or to open a feature request detailling how you would handle it